# Deploying a Flask app with root privileges

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I host a flask web app on a Raspberry Pi that has controls for my LED light strip. It all works great when I run the server with python as the root user, but I am having difficulty deploying it with Apache mod_wsgi. I want to use htttps, so deploying it seems to be necessary, but Apache doesn't seem to allow running servers with root privileges. Root is necessary to control the lights through a library that is imported in the flask server.

Is there any way to deploy a flask server with root privileges? If not, it it possible to use https (from letsencrypt.org) without deploying? Are there any other ways to get around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not run the web server as root for security reasons.

Instead, I suggest to:

1. Add the web user to /etc/sudoers - no password. Ideally, only allow the commands you want to run as root.
2. run the command with sudo [command]

You mention deployment, if you are packaging this into an rpm, I would put the sudo definitions in **/etc/sudoers.d/youpackage**

Another option would be to split you app and use some sort of messaging system - either by having rows in a database table or use a messaging server such as **rabbit mq** (there are other servers but I find it very easy to setup). A separate process running as root would do the actual turning on/off the lights. Your frontend would simply send a message like "lights off" and the other process -which could be running as root- would get a message when needed. The advantage with this approach is that the web process never has any root privilege and even if it has a hole, damage is limited.

Comment: When you say "run the command with sudo [command]", do you mean that I should do the light controls with a subprocess call, or start the server with sudo?

Comment: Not sure what you need to do as root - I assumed it was calling a command/ shell script. You dont want the webserver as root for security reasons. Another option would be to split you app and use some sort of messaging - either a database table or a messaging server like rabbit mq and have the other process run as root. Your frontend would simply send a message like "lights off" and the other process would pick it up

Comment: I have a python LED library that needs access to /dev/mem. Normally I just import it and use it, but that requires the whole server to run as root. I think the idea of separating the web side from the light control side seems logical. I will research interprocess communication. Thanks!

Comment: With pleasure, it is definitely better to do it this way. If you are open to using rabbitmq... it litterally took minutes using their first tutorial to get a function that received messages from another process and it keeps your code simple

Comment: rabbitmq seems like a great option. I'm going though the tutorial now. Thanks again!